# Adding additional criteria to a right join

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportbuilder

This is my first post to this forum and I am very new to SQL so please bear with me.

I am attempting to modify some existing script to make a small change to a report to make it slightly more fit for purpose (the original was put together by a developer).

This report is looking to see whether two specific files have been read into a database for three entities each month or whether they are missing.

The output looks likes the below:

```
File A
YYYY:MM:DD  A  MISSING
            B  MISSING
            C  MISSING

YYYY:MM:DD  A  Present
            B  MISSING
            C  Present
```

The script is such that only the current year files are looked for with the exception of the files for the December of the previous year, however I want to also display the October and November results for the previous year.

Below is the relevant part of the script:

```
select distinct(k.filedate) as filedate, k.fid, case when r.fundid is null then 0 else 1 end as present     
from XXXX database      
right join      
(       
    select convert(date,convert(varchar, year(@ReportDate) - 1) + '-12-01') as filedate, g.fid  
    from (  
        select 'XXXXFDGBP10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXUSD10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXUSD10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXA10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXB10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXGBPMGMT10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXMGMTSH10' as fid
    ) g 

    union   

    select convert(date,convert(varchar, year(@ReportDate)) + '-' + convert(varchar, h.m) + '-01') as filedate, s.fid   
    from (  
        select 'XXXXFDGBP10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXUSD10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXUSD10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXA10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXB10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXGBPMGMT10' as fid
        union
        select 'XXXXMGMTSH10' as fid
    ) s,    
    (   
        select 1 as m
        union
        select 2 as m
        union
        select 3 as m
        union
        select 4 as m
        union
        select 5 as m
        union
        select 6 as m
        union
        select 7 as m
        union
        select 8 as m
        union
        select 9 as m
        union
        select 10 as m
        union
        select 11 as m
        union
        select 12 as m
    ) h 
) k     
on r.fundid = k.fid and r.filedate = k.filedate     
where       
    k.filedate >= convert(date,convert(varchar, year(@ReportDate) - 1) + '-12-01')  
    and k.filedate <= @ReportDate
```

So I want to add '11-01' and '10-01' to the 2016 return of the report. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if this isn't clear or if anyone has any questions.

Comment: Can you not just change the 12 to a 10? That way it will do two additional months each time.

Comment: Apologies for the late response to this suggestion.                                           Unfortunately this just shows the 2016-10 date rather than 2016-10 & 2016-11 & 2016-12 so doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite your query as

```
;WITH months AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) AS f("month")
),
years AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (year(@ReportDate)), (year(@ReportDate)-1)) AS f("year")
),
fids AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('XXXXFDGBP10'), ('XXXXUSD10'), ('XXXXUSD10'), ('XXXXA10'), ('XXXXB10'), ('XXXXGBPMGMT10'), ('XXXXMGMTSH10')) AS f(fid)
),
k AS
(
    SELECT 
        filedate = DATEADD(month, [month]-1, DATEADD(year, [year]-1900, 0)), 
        fid
    FROM fids
    CROSS JOIN years
    CROSS JOIN months
)
SELECT  
    k.filedate, 
    k.fid,
    present = case when r.fundid is null then 0 else 1 end     
FROM XXXX r
RIGHT JOIN k ON r.fundid = k.fid and r.filedate = k.filedate
where       
    k.filedate >= convert(date,convert(varchar, year(@ReportDate) - 1) + '-10-01')  
    and k.filedate <= @ReportDate
```